# Sybase Multiple Updates

Tags: sql, sybase, sql-update

I want to add values to a new column I added to a table.  I need to update about 80 rows and found an answer here that used a similar format as I tried:

```
Update table_name
set column_name = 'G'
where item_id in (6,7,12,15,16,17,22,24,134,166...etc)
```

column_name is CHAR(10) and item_id is an INT

I am getting an error:

```
`Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is illegal when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=, or when the subquery is used as an expression.'
```

I tried just using a set of 3 values and got the same error.  I am too new at it to know why this doesn't work.

It does work one at a time, but I'd rather not  :)

Comment: Put the exact query here please.

Comment: what's the version of Sybase? Do `select @@version` and put here the result.

Comment: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.2/EBF 15967 ESD#6/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase1502/2537/64-bit/FBO/Thu Oct  2 01:33:23 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

```
Update table_name
set column_name = 'G'
where item_id in (6,7,12,15,16,17,22,24,134,166...etc)
```

is your query, I can state that you have a trigger that runs whenever you do an update on table_name.

Your query won't give the error that you stated, so a query inside the trigger must be the problem!

Comment: I looked at the update trigger for that table...there is no message like that in the UPD, INS, or DEL trigger.  Could there be a db-wide thing going on?

Comment: That's weird, the trigger doesn't execute a stored procedure or something like that? Or does upd/ins/del info from a table that might have another trigger?

Comment: I tried to copy it but the comment field doesn't have enough space.  I didn't see any references to any other tables or any other sp though.